# insert image image place holder excel vba powerpoint

Tags: excel, image, vba, powerpoint, placeholder

I am programming an excel VBA macro, which generates a powerpoint presentation from other presentations. Finally a content-slide is generated. Depending on the topics the script should copy the related pictures of this topic to image place holders. At the moment the content slide is populated with the correct text boxes (topic names), but inserting the images does not work.

Intentend pseudo-code:

1. Loop through all slides
2. If you find a slide with a shape named "Content" then:
3. Copy the image located at "image-path" to the image placeholder "FeaturePic2" (for example).

I reduced the code to an example, which does not work. What the code does is:
Copying the image-path-picture to each slide, even if there is no shape named "Content". Secondly it does not populate "FeaturePic2" (which is the second place holder on this slide), but populates the first placeholder it finds.

```
'<<BEGIN>>
On Error Resume Next 
template_path = "C:\test\test.pptx"
image_path = "C:\test\test.jpg"
Set pres_template = pptApp.Presentations.Open(template_path)


For Each slide In pres_template.Slides

       If Shape.Name = ("Content") Then
        slide.Shapes.Placeholders("FeaturePic2").Select msoTrue
        slide.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=image_path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=10, Top:=10
       End If

Next slide

'<<END>>
```

Additional question which might be helpful, too: How can a place holder with a certain name be deleted?

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Also, did you try setting names to the cells into which you want to deploy pictures?

Comment: It does not work: Copying the image-path-picture to each slide, even if there is no shape named "Content". Secondly it does not populate "FeaturePic2" (which is the second place holder on this slide), but populates the first placeholder it finds.
Concerning names to cells? I want to populate powerpoint slides. The script is controlled from an excel vba script, because it needs to read out a table and populate the presentation on basis of this table. I hope I understoond your question correctly.

Comment: And, under which application you are running the VBA, Excel, PowerPoint or via command line?

Comment: Der FDavidov. I am running the VBA under excel and accessing PowerPoint from there.

Comment: OK, this is what I can suggest based on the available info. So, if I understand, you want to create a new PowerPoint presentation using an Excel as the source of steering parameters and one or more other PowerPoint files as sources of images. In that case, I would first suggest considering moving the VBA to PowerPoint. Second, add log printouts to your code at all points where operations take place (e.g. the retrieve params from Excel, the full path of the source PowerPoint file(s), the source Slide, etc., and examine the printed data. You ay find where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The changes below should help with getting the correct picture, assuming that there IS a picture named "Content":

```
On Error Resume Next 
template_path = "C:\test\test.pptx"
image_path = "C:\test\test.jpg"
Set pres_template = pptApp.Presentations.Open(template_path)

' Always DIM your variables and
' Never use reserved names as variable names 
' 
Dim oSl as slide
Dim oSh as shape

For Each oSl In pres_template.Slides
  For each oSh in oSl.Shapes

       If oSh.Name = ("Content") Then
        oSl.Shapes.Placeholders("FeaturePic2").Select msoTrue
        oSl.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=image_path, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=10, Top:=10
       End If

Next ' slide
```

Next, is there some specific reason for putting the picture into a placeholder rather than just adding it as a new picture shape?  It'd be a great deal simpler/more reliable.

If you MUST use a placeholder, you'll probably have to put dummy text or other content into any placeholders you don't want the picture to drop into randomly, then remove the dummy text later.

Comment: I think there is a good reason to use the placeholders. I have two content slides in the presentation (the first one fixed at slide 3, the position of the second one is variable). My idea was to name all placeholders from "FeaturePic1" to "FeaturePic10" and simply drop the related picture for each feature into the "FeaturePic"&i placeholder for each iteration.

Comment: It would be simpler to use e.g. rectangles with those names (FeaturePic1 etc) ...locate the correct shape by name, pick up its coordinates to apply to the new picture that you add to the slide, then delete the shape.

Comment: Okay thanks all (especially FDavidov and Steve). Indeed I switched to an powerpoint macro, which is called by the excel macro via Application.Run. This works much better.