# Fill out IMG placeholder of a powerpoint with VBA

Tags: vba, image, powerpoint, placeholder

I have a question about VBA. I am currently working as a job student in a company where I have to adapt powerpoints to the new desing. Now on each powerpoint there should be a random picture from a certain list. For this purpose, a certain photo place holder is provided in the slidemaster. They say the best way to fill this placeholder is to copy and paste the photo into the placeholder. But I have a powerpoint of 500 slides and I was wondering if there is not a faster way for this that will save me time. I have very little knowledge of VBA myself so. Have already tried some things like the below code snippit from stack overflow but this did not work to solve my problem.

[insert image image place holder excel vba powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338918/insert-image-image-place-holder-excel-vba-powerpoint)

I can possibly put these folders in a folder with certain number and so with a random in VBA so select an image.

Anyone happen to have solution for this problem?

[image: Problem]

Comment: Cross-posted at answers.microsoft.com https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/fill-out-img-placeholder-of-a-powerpoint-with-vba/0061b473-c4c0-44c4-b4ba-2a21ce8e4e24

Comment: @Bartballon Since I've already responded in MS Answers (at the link John posted above), let's follow up there. When we arrive at something that works for you, please post the code here, as an ANSWER to your own question.